# React JS : history.push is not a function error and it isn't navigating to a different page onclick of swal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been using react js for the past couple of months and just got to know about the sweetalert bootstrap plugin for react. on update of a component successfully a dialog appears onscreen. upon clicking the "click here" button history.push is invoked and it should route to a different page but I have been getting error

> history.push is not defined.

I have googled quite a few stuff and tried quite a few scenarios but haven't been successful in it.

code snippet:

```
class displayBlank extends Component {

render(){

<div id="displayDetails">
          <DisplayDetails respData={this.state.respData}  />
        </div>

}

}

export default displayBlank;


class displayDetails{

 handleUpdate()
 {

  // Body of HandleUpdate
    swal({
      title :"Customer Updated Successfully!",
      icon : "success",
      button: "Click Here!",
    }).then((e) => { history.push('/blank');
  });

  }

  render(){

  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>

   Table-Grid Contents
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <td>
              <FormGroup controlId="formControlsDisabledButton"  style={buttonalignment}>
                <Button className="float-right" bsStyle="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Save</Button>
                {'  '}
                <Button className="float-right" bsStyle="primary" type="submit" disabled>Download</Button>
                {'  '}
              </FormGroup>
            </td>


  }

}
```

Comment: Are you using [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/)? That library has a history object with a push method, but it appears you're using window.history, which does not have a push method. If you're not using react-router, maybe you meant [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)?

Comment: @NicholasTower I used history from react-router and I got this : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined and since I am using a react bootstrap template sb-admin-react there is a hstory.js defined in their src and following are the contents : import createHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import createMemoryHistory from 'history/lib/createMemoryHistory';
import useQueries from 'history/lib/useQueries';

const history = useQueries(process.env.BROWSER ? createHistory : createMemoryHistory)();

export default history;
neither work

Comment: Ok, so you're using react router. Is this component one of your routes? If so, react-router should pass a prop in with the history, to be accessed by `this.props.history`. If not, you may need to make use of [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter). It would help if you show your routing code.

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks , I will share the code but on a high level let me explain it this way , There is a blank component which is under routes folder of sb-admin-react-template and blank is the parent component of displayDetails which is the child component which is being invoked from blank and once I click on the pop-up after update I want it routed back to blank which is the parent component , hence I am using history.push('/blank) , I hope I am clear on this , The parent component is a lengthy code hence posted just displayDetails

Comment: I have posted the updated code too , Please let me know if this is sufficient or I can elaborate on this , Thanks for your help again

Comment: 1. `history` is available on the props of the `Routes` declared in the `Router`, first you need to make sure of being on that component. 2. You need to get the history from the props like this: `const { history } = this.props`, 3. You need to read more about the React-router based on the version you're using.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're using [react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router), use `this.props.history.push('<url>')`.

If you're stumbling across a `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error, wrap the component in [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class DisplayBlank extends Component {
  ...
}

export default withRouter(DisplayBank);
```

Answer (score 6):

hi there  if  you are facing  the issue  with

> history.push  in react js     try  this

- 

```
 import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
        const history= useNavigate();
   
   history("/path");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the `history` from `props` as an object in the function argument.

```
function =({history})=>{
   return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```